# what are the root causes that lead to the 2008 economic recession?

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-economics, financial-markets, financial-crises, great-recession

looking at factors that were the roots of the recession in the late 2000s, mortgage-backed securities was one. Can the community reinvestment act be counted as another? Are there any other factors that could be root causes but are generally overlooked?

Comment: Hi, there are already posts on this site that address this, do some of them answer your question? You should always research the site first before posting. E.g. see https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/46001/was-the-financial-crash-of-2008-caused-by-top-graduates-of-the-american-ivy-leag/46002#46002; https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/what-actually-went-wrong-in-the-economy-as-described-by-the-big-short?rq=1 or https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/26750/was-the-2008-financial-crisis-caused-more-by-the-us-subprime-mortgage-lending-or?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was the financial crash of 2008 caused by top graduates of the American Ivy Leagues working at wall street banks?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/46001/was-the-financial-crash-of-2008-caused-by-top-graduates-of-the-american-ivy-leag)